# Submit Django HTML form with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, django, ajax

This is my first time trying to submit a form with Ajax.

Here's my code:

**index.html** (where the form is declared):

```
form method="post" role="form" class="email-form" id="contact_me">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required /></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3" id="thankyou">

                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
                        </form>
```

There is a  is reserved to display the message after the form is submitted.

**views.py:**

```
def send_message(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        sender_name = request.POST.get('name')
        sender_email = request.POST.get('email')
        message_subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message_text = request.POST.get('message')

        html_message = render_to_string('contact_template.html', {'sender_name': sender_name, 'sender_email': sender_email, 'message_subject': message_subject, 'message_text': message_text})

        email_subject = 'Message from website visitor'
        email_from = 'me@mygmail.com'
        email_to = ['me@mydomain.com']

        send_mail(email_subject, '', email_from, email_to, html_message=html_message)

        response = {
            'thankyou': 'Your message has been sent. Thank you!'
        }

        return JsonResponse(response)
```

**urls.py:**

```
path('sendmessage/', views.send_message, name='send_message'),
```

**And the Ajax script** (index.html):

```
<script>
$('#contact_me').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/sendmessage/",
        data: {
            sender_name : $('#name').val(),
            sender_email : $('#email').val(),
            message_subject : $('#subject').val(),
            message_text : $('#message').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}',
            datatype : "json",
        },

        success: function(data){
            $('#thankyou').html('<div class="sent-message">' + data.msg + '</div>')
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I fill the form and click on Submit, the page is reloading (but it shouldn't) and no email is sent, no Thank You message is shown.

Please assist.

**EDIT:**

I found some missing ',' in the script and edited "urls.py" and now I receive the e-mail, but:

In the email, I see "None" for sender's name, email address, etc.

The Thank You message is not shown. I see "undefined". Actually I don't know how to include the full html tag I need in the script.

Comment: Your csrf token is literal is missing a quote. It should be `'{{csrf_token}}'`. And comma after that is also missing.

Comment: Thank you. It is corrected but the main issue is not solved.

Comment: Your JS looks correct, not sure what your issue could be, can you check your console for JS errors and also check the network tab if api doesn't return any error. Also, you can check your django terminal if there are any errors.

Comment: I checked the console and found one error: "Unexpected identifier" and it is referring to the script line: url : "/sendmessage/". I have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: you've missed commas after `type: "POST",` and `url : "/sendmessage/",`, add those and it should work.

Comment: Yes I noticed and updated the code, but now there's another issue. I edited my original post to explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter names in the JavaScript and the view doesn't match. That is the problem here. Modify your AJAX script as follows to fix the issue:

```
<script>
$('#contact_me').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/sendmessage/",
        data: {
            name : $('#name').val(),
            email : $('#email').val(),
            subject : $('#subject').val(),
            message : $('#message').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}',
            datatype : "json",
        },

        success: function(data){
            $('#thankyou').html('<div class="sent-message">' + data.msg + '</div>')
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't see the difference between your code and mine.

Comment: Check the parameter name in `data` parameter of the AJAX call.

Comment: Glad to help. 